# Receive LoRaWAN uplink messages through ThingPark Community Network Server

Tags: iot, lorawan

How can an Application Server receive and verify the integrity of a LoRaWAN message forwarded by Actility ThingPark Community Network Server?

Answer (score 0):

ThingPark Community Network Server can forward LoRaWAN uplink messages to Application Servers by means of HTTP POST messages. Every http request sent by ThingPark to the AS is validated by a one-time token so that the AS can verify the integrity of the request by recalculating that token and comparing it with the one sent by ThingPark.

The interface between [ThingPark Enterprise Network Server](https://docs.thingpark.com/thingpark-enterprise/6.1/Content/Home.htm) and an external Application Server is described in the [TPE LRC AS tunnel interface development guide](https://docs.thingpark.com/thingpark-enterprise/6.1/Content/TPE-LRC-AS-tunnel-interface-dev-guide.htm).

For a quick test please check our [simple javascript example](https://github.com/actility/thingpark-integrations/blob/main/1_tpNS-AS/AS_nodejs_example/verify_token_in_uplink.js) that demonstrates how you can verify the integrity of an uplink message.
You must update the script with your actual *AS_KEY*, *POST body* and *QueryParams*.

- *POST body* and *QueryParams* are sent by ThingPark to the AS via the http POST request
- The *AS_KEY* is the *Tunnel Interface Authentication Key* that you set on the [CREATE HTTP APPLICATION](https://docs.thingpark.com/thingpark-enterprise/6.1/Content/Connecting-to-HTTPS-application.htm) form.

For your convenience, we have created several [AS examples](https://github.com/actility/thingpark-integrations/tree/main/1_tpNS-AS) (nodeJS, nodeRED, PHP, Python, curl) that can help you to start application server development.